# ffmpeg: how do I disable use of the video's capture time for video timestamps?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm a pilot, and have a GoPro camera that I use to film flights. Typically I concatenate the multiple output files produced by the camera with something like this:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

This has always worked well, and continues to do so. But after reinstalling my OS and ffmpeg, I found that there is a new feature: when playing the video in QuickTime Player, the timestamp shown is now the capture time of the video. For example, the beginning of my latest video of a flight starting at about 8:49am shows 08:49:00:06, insead of 0:00:00 as usual.

This is nifty, but it breaks my workflow around annotating timestamps in the video for later reference. How do I turn it off?

Comment: Share full log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is called a 'timecode', and I was able to make this work as follows:

```
 ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -c copy -timecode 00:00:00:00 output.mp4
```